App deleted, but icon still there in the apps menu
I installed Steam from the Ubuntu software store. The app installed fine. It ran well for the first few minutes until it started misbehaving.
I decided to remove Steam, but I was unable to do that directly via the app store.  I decided to use the terminal. I thought Steam got uninstalled. But I just came across the Steam icon today in my apps list. It wouldn't run though. I used the terminal to try to remove it, but the result showed me that no such app was found installed.
I then headed to the app store and found Steam among the list of installed apps. I uninstalled it from there, and it did get uninstalled. But the app icon is still there.
I thought this might be a case of a remnant desktop icon. So I headed to the ~/.local/share/applications/ folder, but there is nothing there. Not sure what else to do.

Never mind. The icon is gone now. Man, 24.04 is really weird. From installation to deleting apps.... it just keeps acting up and then the issue gets resolved on its own after while for some reason.
